# Calculator's history in local storage even on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, dom-events, calculator

I am doing a calculator that stores a history of previous calculations and list it in a table. The list needs to be stored in local storage of the web browser.

Since data is stored on local storage it should not lose context even on page refresh.

I am attaching my Javascript code below:

```
let currentTotal = 0; 
let buffer = "0"; //what's on display

let previousOperator = null;

const calcScreen = document.querySelector(".calc-numbers");

document.querySelector('.calculator-buttons').addEventListener("click",function(event){

    //call function buttonClick
    buttonClick(event.target.innerHTML);
});

//separates de value of the button clicks into NotANumber and Numbers
function buttonClick(value){
    if(isNaN(parseInt(value))){
        handleSymbol(value);
    }else{
        handleNumber(value);
    }
    rerenderScreen();
}

function handleSymbol(value){
    switch (value){
        case "C":
            buffer = "0";
            currentTotal = 0;
            previousOperator = null;
            break;
        case "=":
            if(previousOperator === null){ //this would mean that there is nothing to be calculated yet
                return;
            }
            flushOperation(parseInt(buffer));
            buffer = "" + currentTotal;
            previousOperator = null;
            currentTotal = 0;
            break;
        case "←":
            if(buffer.length === 1){ //if the screen is any single number, always turn it to 0 when deleting
                buffer = "0";
            }
            else{
                buffer = buffer.substring(0,buffer.length-1); //delete the numbers one by one
            }
            break;
        default:
            handleMath(value);
            break;
    }
}

function handleNumber(value){
    if(buffer === "0"){
        buffer = value;
    }else{
        buffer += value;
    }
}

function handleMath(value){
    const internalBuffer = parseInt(buffer);
    
    if (currentTotal === 0){
        currentTotal = internalBuffer;
    }else{
        flushOperation(internalBuffer);
    }

    previousOperator = value;

    buffer = "0";
}

function flushOperation(internalBuffer){
    if(previousOperator === "+"){
        currentTotal += internalBuffer;
    }else if(previousOperator === "-"){
        currentTotal -= internalBuffer;
    }else if(previousOperator === "x"){
        currentTotal *= internalBuffer;
    }else{
        currentTotal /= internalBuffer;
    }
}

function rerenderScreen(){
    calcScreen.value = buffer;
}
```

I referred this link [how to add a localstorage for my Calculator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446887/how-to-add-a-localstorage-for-my-calculator)

I added this code under my previous Javascript code:

```
let itemsArray = []
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'))
 
itemsArray.push(input.value)
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray))
```

I refreshed my page. But the data is not stored locally. I tried typing localstorage in console but it was empty.

Adding screenshot of the result obtained in console tab

[image]

Iam getting this error too at the same time

> Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined

Comment: We are here to help you with problems you cannot solve yourself, even after trying. Just saying: "Unfortunately it doesnt work.", doesn't imply much effort on your part. What have you tried? Have you used the developer tools in the browser to see what is happening? Is it a storage or retrieval problem?

Comment: It would really help if you could narrow down the problem a bit like what @KIKOSoftware said. Take a look at the console in the browser devtools to see if you're getting any errors. And instead of trying to do everything in one go, maybe try just to store a little bit of data on localstorage and see if that works. Once you get that right, add the calculator code.

Comment: when you say it was empty, do you mean localStorage was empty or the array "items" was empty?

Comment: I have attached an image in my question.

Comment: So the code was copied, but I don't see `input` within your code? ... so what should be added to the array instead of `input`, the `event.target.innerHTML`, or ? You may need to update the question's code with all the latest updates for better context of how it's all put together.

Comment: Welcome!
As noted, no sign of `input` being defined in your code.
Regardless, here is how I would use `localStorage`:
Somewhere, in the code that creates the page, I would load data from `localStorage`, similar to what you did: `data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));`, and then continue page creation with the `data`.
Anywhere the user/code changes the/adds to - the `data`, I'd store it in `localStorage`, similar to what you did: `localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));`.